# HttpClient for remote secure Login

Tags: c#

I am attempting a programatic login to a remote host to update settings when required. My Login is failing with 404, this is my code:

```
public async void Go(string url)
{

    // Create a Uri:
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

    // Create and configure ClientHandler:
    HttpClientHandler ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = true,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
        Credentials = null,
        MaxAutomaticRedirections = 7,
        MaxRequestContentBufferSize = 1024 * 2,
        PreAuthenticate = false,
        Proxy = new WebProxy(),
        UseCookies = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        UseProxy = false
    };

    // Create a new HttpClient and parse in the ClientHandler:
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler);

    // Get the Uri Async, required to get Cookies:
    string html = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

    // Get the Cookies from the Cookie Container:
    CookieCollection collection = ClientHandler.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);

    // Attempt Login:
    html = await client.GetStringAsync(BuildUri(html)); // 404 occurs here.
    }

    private string GetToken(string html)
    {

        string look = "ajax_token: '";
        string to = "',";
        int StartIndex = html.IndexOf(look) + look.Length;

        html = html.Substring(StartIndex);
        int EndIndex = html.IndexOf(to);
        string token = html.Substring(0, EndIndex);

        return token;
    }

    private string BuildUri(string html)
    {

        string token = GetToken(html);

        string Parameters = "/ajax_token=" + token 
                          + "&action=" + "login" 
                          + "&username_login=" + Username 
                          + "&password_login=" + Password;

        // Concatinate Uri and Params;
        string URI = "https://www.crazydomains.com.au/ajax/top-shopping-cart" + Parameters;

        return (URI);
    }
```

The Uri I am logging into is:

```
https://www.crazydomains.com.au/
```

I am attempting to update my DNS A and MX Records via Code as my IP Changes.
Using Fiddler, the Uri appears to be correct that I am building for the POST.

```
https://www.crazydomains.com.au/ajax/top-shopping-cart/ajax_token=<TOKEN>&action=login&username_login=<USERNAME>&password_login=<PASSWORD>
```

I don't understand why I am getting a 404, Cookies appear to be correct and working, and the Uri and credentials appear to be correct. If someone can point out my problem, what I am doing wrong, I would be very greatful!

EDIT: I have also tried:

```
// Get the Token:
string token = GetToken(html);

// Conf Params:
string Parameters = "ajax_token=" + token
                  + "&action=" + "login"
                  + "&username_login=" + Username
                  + "&password_login=" + Password;

// Post URI:
string PostURI = "https://www.crazydomains.com.au/ajax/top-shopping-cart/";

// Init Content:
HttpContent content = new StringContent(Parameters, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

// Attempt Login:
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(PostURI, content);
```

I still get 404 ;-(

Comment: just realised.. `https://www.crazydomains.com.au/ajax/top-shopping-cart/ajax_token=<TOKEN>....` is it `/ajax_token` or `?ajax_token` ? it seems you url is wrong.. should be `https://www.crazydomains.com.au/ajax/top-shopping-cart?ajax_token`

Comment: 404 points to Uri problem, I tried your suggestion but still 404.